# Transform (large) XML-files into relational SQL

Tags: c#, sql, xml, linq, entity-framework

I've been tasked with the job of importing a set of XML files, transform them and upload them to an SQL database, and then re-transforming them to a different XML-format.

The XML files are rather large, and some of them a little complex, so I'm unsure of the best way to do this. I'd of course like to automate this process somehow - and was actually hoping there'd be some kind of Entity Framework-esque solution to this.

I'm quite new to handling and dealing with XML in .NET, so I don't really know what my options are. I've read about XSLT, but that seems to me, to be a "language" I need to learn first, making it kind of not a solution for me.

Just to set a bit of context, the final solution actually needs to import new/updated versions of the XML on a weekly basis, uploading the new data to sql, and re-exporting as the other XML-format.

If anyone could give me any ideas as to how to proceed, I'd be much obliged.

My first instict was to use something like [XSD2DB](http://xsd2db.sourceforge.net/) or [XML SPY](http://www.altova.com/xmlspy.html) to first create the database structure, but I don't really see how I'm then supposed to proceed either.

I'm quite blank in fact :)

Comment: This feels like something C# could manage OTB. Might come back with an answer soon (at work atm).

Answer (score 0):

XSLT is language used by XML processors to transform XML document in one format to XML document in another format. XSLT would be your choice if you don't need to store data in database as well.

All tools like XSD2DB or XML SPY will create some database schema for you but the quality of the schema will be very dependent on quality of XML document and XSD (do you have XSD or are you going to generate it from sample XML?). The generated database will probably not be to much useful for EF.

If you have XSD you can use xsd.exe tool shipped with Visual studio and generate classes representing data of your XML files in .NET code. You will be able to use `XmlSerializer` to deserialize the XML document into your generated classes. The problem is that some XSD constructs like `choice` are modeled in .NET code by very ugly way. Another problem can be performance if your XML files are really huge because deserialization must read all data at once. The last problem can be again EF - classes generated by XSD will most probably not be usable as entities and you will not be able to map them.

So either use EF and in such case you will have to analyze XSD and create custom entities and mapping to your own designed database and you will fill your classes either from `XmlReader` (best performance), `XmlDocument` or `XDocument` or use some tool helping you creating classes or database from XML and in such case use direct SQL to work with a database.

Reverse operation will again require custom approach. You will have data represented either by your custom EF entities or by some autogenerated classes and you will have to transform them to a new format. You can again use xsd.exe to get classes for a new format and write a custom .NET code filling new classes from old ones (and use `XmlSerializer` to persist a new structure to XML) or you can use `XmlWriter`, `XDocument` or `XmlDocument` to build target XML document directly.

Data migration in any form is not easy task with ready to use solution. In case of really huge data processing you can use tools like SQL Server Integration Services where you will interact with XML and SQL directly and process data in batches.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at SQLXML 4.0. It does exactly what you want (in upload part).